# Signing a JSON payload

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a way to provide an signature verification method to an payload.
Since the payload consist of Json serialized data i figured that the best way to do that is to use Json Web Signature.
The problem is i am having hard time finding any examples of how this can be done in .NET c#.

StackOverflow also have a zero answered questions on the topic.

Can anyone who had experience with it elaborate ?

Comment: The term you might be missing when searching is "json web token" or jwt rather than "Json web signature".  Have a look at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) for instance - they've got a section on libraries available in different languages, including .NET/C#.

Comment: I am talking about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Signature , as i understand its part of JWT but JWT is not what i am looking for.

Comment: TBH my quick skim reading of that sounds like JWS is a proposed standardisation of what JWT already is...

Comment: Well i am not sure myself so thats why i am asking, i could just take they binary payload and attach a signature at the end and then verify with public key BUT if there is a standard way i could use it would be preferable.